# Toggle Event Color with css-class in Fullcalendar v5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I would like to mark a clicked event by adding a css class ('click_class'). Clicking the event again should remove the 'click_class'.
As a starting point I would like to know which value in the object should be changed if you want to add a persistent CSS class to an event after a eventClick?

```
cl_object = calendar.getEventById( id );
cl_object.setProp('eventClassNames','click_class');
calendar.render();
```

or

```
cl_object.ui.setProp('classNames','click_class');
calendar.render();
```

Both doesn't work

The classes are defined in this event object

```
classNames_arr = cl_object.ui.classNames;
```

as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

// Maybe like this

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    //
    // classNames Object
    classNames_obj = info.event.classNames;
    //
    // Transform into array
    classNames_arr = Object.values(classNames_obj);
    //
    // check, whether the class is here
    if (classNames_arr.includes('click_class')){
        // already here => remove
        classNames_arr = arrayRemove(classNames_arr, 'click_class');
    } else {
        //append
        classNames_arr.push('click_class');
    }
    // Update fullcalendar event object
    info.event.setProp('classNames',classNames_arr);
},
```

```
// Function
function arrayRemove(arr, value) { return arr.filter(function(ele){ return ele != value; });}
```